# How to check if directory exist in post build action of msbuild

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I've migrated a project from VS2015 to VS2017 and I've noticed that sometimes building a solution that has a postbuild step it fails on the mkdir if the directory currently exists.
Both VS runs as administrator and the postbuild action is made of two steps.
The first makes a directory if it doesn't exist, the second creates a nuget package of the assembly and copies it to the folder..

I've read the docs but haven't find a solution to check if the directory exists

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2448zz7.aspx: `<MakeDir Directories="myDir" Condition="!Exists('myDir')"/>`. Put this inside a target like `<Target Name="CreateSomeDir" AfterTargets="Build"/>`

Comment: Hello, but have I to add it to the proj file manually or have I specify it in the vs textbox where I put the code for post build action?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned: yes that has to be added to the project file manually as it is msbuild code. The build events customizable by the gui only take cmd command line code. Of course you could also use that, should be something like `IF NOT EXIST myDir (mkdir myDir)` but I can never remember the correct sntax so I might be wrong.

Comment: I figured out how to check for the existence of a directory within the command line GUI:
 **IF NOT EXIST "$(TargetDir)AndroidDebugBridge" mkdir "$(TargetDir)AndroidDebugBridge"** This eliminated the build errors because the directory or files already existed.

Comment: Or, for PC with Windows:  if not exist "C:\MyDLLFolder" mkdir "C:\MyDLLFolder"